# Trace a created canvas path using HTML5, JAVASCRIPT and move it as you trace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, trace

I have created:
an HTML5 canvas 100% width and height of screen with taphold and tapmove event listeners.

I would like to create:
a vertically  curved canvas line (Bezier) that is the height of the canvas,
And moves downward on taphold until touch ends while
the actual point(s) on the line being touched change color as you trace the line

As the line is moving downward, the line is continually generating from the top of the page

id like this vertically curvy line to be neverending if touchhold persists

If your touch lands outside the line:
//alert something

Comment: Lines are pretty much...well...linear(!).  What do you mean by "randomly shaped"?  Code would be helpful.

Comment: Curvy line, endless. Im just starting out with concept,  no code as of now. Assistance appreciated markE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/k5KsC/

OK, here is code to draw a curvey line down the canvas and turn that line a different color as the user drags across the line (I use mouse instead of drag, but you can substitute touch).

The concepts involved in making this work are fairly complex so your "homework" is to (1) Google these concepts and (2) learn how they work and (3) see how they are applied in the code.

- mouse and touch events
- drawing quadratic and Bezier curves in canvas
- creating a spline in canvas (your curvey vertical line is actually a spline)
- globalCompositeOperation in canvas (this is used to change the line color as the user drags)

Here is example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth=5;
    ctx.fillStyle="maroon";

    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    var isDown=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;

    var $alert=$("#alert");
    var curves;
    var maxY=0;

    drawCurveyLine();

    function drawCurveyLine(){

        var points=[];

        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
            var x=Math.random()*20+10;
            var y=i*canvas.height/9;
            points.push(x);
            points.push(y);
        }

        curves=calculateSplineCurves(points,.25);

        drawSpline(curves,"skyblue")

    }

    function calculateSplineCurves(pts,t){
        var cp=[];   // array of control points, as x0,y0,x1,y1,...
        var n=pts.length;
        var curves=[];

        // Draw an open spline
        for(var i=0;i<n-4;i+=2){
            cp=cp.concat(getControlPoints(pts[i],pts[i+1],pts[i+2],pts[i+3],pts[i+4],pts[i+5],t));
        }    
        // Q-start
        curves.push({x0:pts[0],y0:pts[1],x1:cp[0],y1:cp[1],x2:pts[2],y2:pts[3]});
        // B-curves
        for(var i=2;i<pts.length-5;i+=2){
            ctx.beginPath();
            curves.push({x0:pts[i],y0:pts[i+1],x1:cp[2*i-2],y1:cp[2*i-1],x2:cp[2*i],y2:cp[2*i+1],x3:pts[i+2],y3:pts[i+3]});
        }
        // Q-end
        curves.push({x0:pts[n-4],y0:pts[n-3],x1:cp[2*n-10],y1:cp[2*n-9],x2:pts[n-2],y2:pts[n-1]});

        return(curves);

    }


    //
    function drawSpline(curves,linecolor){

        // Q-starting
        var q=curves[0];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(q.x0,q.y0);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(q.x1,q.y1,q.x2,q.y2);

        // B's
        for(var i=1;i<curves.length-1;i++){
            var b=curves[i];
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(b.x1,b.y1,b.x2,b.y2,b.x3,b.y3);       
        }
        // Q-ending
        var q=curves[curves.length-1];
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(q.x1,q.y1,q.x2,q.y2);

        ctx.strokeStyle=linecolor;
        ctx.stroke();
    };

    //
    function getControlPoints(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,t){
        var d01=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x0,2)+Math.pow(y1-y0,2));
        var d12=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+Math.pow(y2-y1,2));
        var fa=t*d01/(d01+d12);
        var fb=t-fa;
        var p1x=x1+fa*(x0-x2);
        var p1y=y1+fa*(y0-y2);
        var p2x=x1-fb*(x0-x2);
        var p2y=y1-fb*(y0-y2);  
        return [p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y];
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      if(mouseX>60){
          $alert.text("You are outside the line!");
      }else{
          if(mouseY>maxY){
              maxY=mouseY;
              $alert.text("OK");
              ctx.save();
              ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop"
              ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,maxY);
              ctx.restore();
          }
      }

    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4 id="alert">Drag down the curvey line.</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=500></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @GameAlchemist: This is my first question on this site,I will clarify my queries for more answers, suggestions appreciated. No need for negativity. MarkE I will try this demo and reach out to you if need be. Thank you for taking the time to help

Comment: Ive tried this code out and is is what Im looking for! It does trace as I trace over it (from the top). I can take it from here! Thanks so much markE!